# can I zipping big size folder without long time open the ssh in google cloud

Tags: cloud

i would like to know how can I zipping big size folder without long time open the ssh in google cloud.

there is a folder contain over 100G images. google cloud seems must need me open the ssh to execute the zipping. but it may need one day online the PC,

and method zipping the folder itself offline after I execute the zipping?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a terminal session manager like screen/tmux. Instructions for tmux (screen should be similar)

1. SSH to host
2. Install tmux
3. Launch `tmux`
4. Launch your zip command
5. Disconnect from the session <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> <kbd>d</kbd>
6. Log out

When you want to check if it is completed

1. SSH to host
2. Connect to the session using `tmux attach`